# New `onCharacteristicRead` method not working

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

after an embarrassing amount of time I have just found out that the new recommended receiver for `onCharacteristicRead` in `BluetoothGattCallback` as seen in the [Android Developers reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback#onCharacteristicRead(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic,%20byte%5B%5D,%20int)):

```kotlin
public void onCharacteristicRead (BluetoothGatt gatt, 
                BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, 
                byte[] value, 
                int status)
```

doesn't receive any data when I call `readCharacteristic` on the service. However, the deprecated one ([Google Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback#onCharacteristicRead(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic,%20int))) does in fact receive the callback.

I have been following all the steps in the [official guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/transfer-ble-data#read), but trying to implement the new methods, and this is the only one so far that doesn't work in the "new callbacks".

Any ideas on how to fix this? I will use the deprecated method, but that's not something I'm keen on. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new api's are only available as of Android 13.

So

- Make sure your phone is on Android 13
- Set "compileSdkVersion 33" in your build.gradle
- Set "targetSdkVersion 33" in your builld.gradle

After that, it shouuld work. At least it did for me...

Comment: Therefore I should keep both methods, the new one for Android 13, and the old one for older versions?

Comment: Yes, indeed. If you want to support older versions you need to implement both

Comment: Okay then, I'll implement both. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

When using compileSdk 33 there is a separation - on Android 13 a new function is called, on Android 12 and below a Deprecated one. To add support for older Android versions just add this to your code:

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
@Deprecated(
    "Used natively in Android 12 and lower",
    ReplaceWith("onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, characteristic.value, status)")
)
override fun onCharacteristicRead(
    gatt: BluetoothGatt,
    characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic,
    status: Int
) = onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, characteristic.value, status)
```

Some other functions require the same changes:

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
@Deprecated(
    "Used natively in Android 12 and lower",
    ReplaceWith("onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic, characteristic.value)")
)
override fun onCharacteristicChanged(
    gatt: BluetoothGatt,
    characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic
) = onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic, characteristic.value)
```