# BLE's - onCharacteristicRead not invoked on calling readCharacteristic

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt, android-ble

I'm trying to read a value from a custom characteristic in a custom service on a BLE device.
I successfully call the `readCharcteristic` method as it returns `true`. However, the `onCharacteristicRead` callback function is never invoked. I am unable to determine why this is so.

My read function is as follows (there is no pending or ongoing read or write request when this method if called) -

```
fun readOneSpecificCharacteristic() {

    if (lpnInfoChar?.isReadable() == true) {
    
        Log.i("READ", "READABLE")
    
        if (btGatt?.readCharacteristic(lpnInfoChar) == true) {
            Log.i("READ", "INIT SUCCESS") //<- my code reaches here
        } else {
            Log.i("READ", "INIT FAIL")
        }
    
    } else {
        Log.i("READ", "NOT READABLE")
    }
}
```

My Callback (which is never invoked) -

```
private val gattCallback = object: BluetoothGattCallback() {

    override fun onCharacteristicRead(
        gatt: BluetoothGatt,
        characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic,
        value: ByteArray,
        status: Int
    ) {
    
        Log.i("Callback", "onCharacteristicRead")
    
        with(characteristic) {
            when (status) {
                BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS -> {
                    Log.i("BluetoothGattCallback", "Read characteristic $uuid:\n${value.toHexString()}")
                }
                BluetoothGatt.GATT_READ_NOT_PERMITTED -> {
                    Log.e("BluetoothGattCallback", "Read not permitted for $uuid!")
                }
                else -> {
                    Log.e("BluetoothGattCallback", "Characteristic read failed for $uuid, error: $status")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The other callbacks work as expected - I am able to write, read rssi value, discover service etc.

Additionally, I know that the BLE device is working fine since BLE scanning apps form the PlayStore are able to read the value from it.

Where `gattCallback` is registered -

```
override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult) {

            if (isScanning) {
                stopScan()
            }

            with(result.device) {
                Log.i("ScanCallback", "Found BLE device! Name: ${name ?: "Unnamed"}, address: $address")
                setGeneralStatusText("BLE Device Found - ${name ?: "Unnamed"}")

                Log.i("ScanResultAdapter", "Connecting to $address")
                setGeneralStatusText("Connecting to ${name ?: "Unnamed"} - $address")
                connectGatt(baseContext, true, gattCallback, BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you post the code where you register `gattCallback`? Are you making sure that you're only reading one characteristic at any time and waiting for its result, as BLE does not support multiple read requests at the same time?

Comment: @DanielF I am definitely reading only one characteristic at a time with no ongoing read or write request. I am updating the question with the code requested.

Comment: I don't know, I'm sorry.

Comment: Is it possible that you read characteristic before the connection is ready?

Comment: @DanielF I found the issue. Please see my posted answer.

Comment: @Kozmotronik I found the issue. Please see my posted answer.

Comment: Good one @KK. I upvoted both your question and answer. You made me note about those API changes for Android 13. Hence I'm gonna update my projects soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the deprecated method needed to be called. More info here -

[New `onCharacteristicRead` method not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73438580/new-oncharacteristicread-method-not-working)